# Angular acceleration of falling disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, acceleration

**Question: A disk of radius 0.10 m falls vertically with its axis horizontal, unwinding a string whose other end is attached above. What is the angular acceleration of the disk in $\mathsf{rad/s^2}$?**

My solution:

$$\tau = I\alpha$$
$$\alpha = \frac{a}{r}$$
$$\tau = Fr$$
$$I_{disk} = \frac{1}{2}mr^2$$
So...
$$Fr = \frac{1}{2}mr^2\frac{a}{r}$$
Then to calculate F:
$$F = ma$$
$$T - mg = ma$$
$$T = m(g+a)$$

Replacing F in the first equation with T:
$$m(g+a)r = \frac{1}{2}mr^2\frac{a}{r}$$
After simplifying...
$$g+a = \frac{1}{2}a$$
$$a = -2g$$
By the earlier equation $\alpha = \frac{a}{r}$ we get $\alpha = \frac{-2g}{r}$
which gives $\alpha = \frac{-2(9.8)}{0.10} = -196$ ignoring the direction and giving 2 significant figures I get the answer **200** $\mathsf{rad/s^2}$.

This was a multiple choice exam problem and there have been other times they put the wrong answer down on the Scantron key. If I am wrong, I would appreciate it if someone could show me why. The answer given on the Scantron is **65 $\mathsf{rad/s^2}$**.

Comment: This seems like it would belong more on [this site](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/?qa=questions); here I don't think it is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sign problem. The disc is accelerating downwards so you would expect the weight of the disc $mg$ to be greater in magnitude than the tension in the string $T$ so with down as positive applying N2L gives $mg -T = ma$

Comment: It gives $Tr = m(g-a)r= \frac a2 r \Rightarrow a= \frac{2g}{3}$ which is more reasonable as you would expect the linear acceleration to be less than $g$?

Comment: omg you're right sorry! thats it and that gives 65

Comment: So it was all because I set it up with the tension being greater than mg, which doesn't make sense. Okay thank you! @Farcher